# Why does this ternary statement produce a different result to this identical if / else statement?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Imagine that I have the following Java code:

```java
Object value = -4;
    
Object result = (value instanceof Integer) ? (-((int)value)) : (-((double)value));

System.out.println(result);
```

The expectation is that this would print `4`. The `value` variable is clearly an integer, and therefore the first branch of the ternary statement should be taken, resulting in it being cast as an `int`, and negated.

However, this is not what happens, and instead this results in a value of `4.0`; meaning that somehow the false branch of the ternary statement is being taken instead (presumably).

Now, lets take the following Java code:

```java
Object value = -4;

Object result;
    
if (value instanceof Integer) {
    result = -((int)value);
}
else {
    result = -((double)value);
}
        
System.out.println(result);
```

This should be functionally equivalent to the ternary statement, as it is the same logic, but just expanded into the full if / else format. However, it correctly prints the value as the integer `4`.

---

There are some interesting points to note:

- If I change the else branch of the ternary to a different value (e.g. just the string `"A"`), then the number is cast as an int correctly. For example:

  ```java
  Object result = (value instanceof Integer) ? (-((int)value)) : "A";
  ```

  produces the result of `4`.
- If I print out just the condition, it is always true -- the object `value` *is* always an integer (and therefore the true path *should* always run):

  ```java
  System.out.println(value instanceof Integer);
  ```

My personal suspicion based on the two points above is that the ternary is running correctly, and then somehow the integer value is being cast as a double. However, I have no idea how this could be happening.

Another possible explanation could be that this is some sort of compiler bug -- for this reason I'll mention that this is JavaSE 12.0.2 running in Eclipse on macOS 11 beta 3.

Comment: So from the other answer, it is using the first branch of the ternary operator as expected, but that value is a double.